# Finding the mixture of two gamma distributions

Tags: probability-theory, mixing

I am going through the theory behind mixing distributions, and I came across a portion in an essay where it talks about mixing two gamma distributions, it does not show how to get the resulting distribution. But I am interested if you could somehow.

So the question goes like this:

We have $S|\Lambda \sim \Gamma(\alpha,\Lambda) $ and $\Lambda\sim\Gamma(\beta, \mu) $, we want to find $S$ such that the pdf of S is: $$ f_S(s) = \int_0^\infty f_{S|\Lambda=\lambda}(s) f_\Lambda(\lambda)d\lambda $$
So far I have that:
$$
f_S(s) = \int_0^\infty ( \frac {s^{\alpha-1}e^{-s/\lambda}}{\lambda^{\alpha}\Gamma(\alpha)} ) ( \frac {\lambda^{\beta-1}e^{-\lambda/\mu}}{\mu^{\beta}\Gamma(\beta)} )d\lambda = \frac{s^{\alpha-1}}{\mu^\beta\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^\infty \lambda^{\beta-\alpha-1}e^{-(s/\lambda+\lambda/\mu)}d\lambda 
$$
I tried various substitutions and manipulations etc, can't figure how to evaluate this integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind special functions:
$$
f_S(s)=\frac{2} {\Gamma (\alpha ) \Gamma (\beta )s}\left(\frac{s}{\mu}\right)^{\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}} K_{\alpha -\beta }\left(2 \sqrt{\frac{s}{\mu }}\right),
$$
where $K$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: Is this distribution not a well defined one? The way exponential mixed with gamma produces Pareto?

Comment: You mean a "well-known" distribution? (It's perfectly well-defined.) Not that I know of. If $1/\Lambda$ were gamma-distributed, it would be a compound gamma distribution.

Comment: Thank you! Very well explained!

Comment: is there any chance you can show what was the substitution you made to get that substitution?

Comment: Sure, $u=\log\left(\lambda/\sqrt{\mu s}\right)$.